# How to solve "Encountered unresolved custom op: SimpleMLCreateModelResource." in TensorFlow Model in Android app?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have trained a TensorFlow Model using the [GradientBoostedTreesModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/api_docs/python/tfdf/keras/GradientBoostedTreesModel) and converted it to a TensorFlow light model using a python script.

Loading the model in my Android app gives me following error message which i cannot resolve:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: 
Encountered unresolved custom op: SimpleMLCreateModelResource.
    See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom
```

The mentioned instructions do not provide any valuable information. I have included the TensorFlow lite and tf ops dependencies.

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.8.0'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.8.0'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.3.1'
```

My Model was trained in a TensorFlow 2.8.0 environment.